# Find the "Project" Count for particular "User" for different days of interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
user_table
........................................
| user_id   |  user_name  |  password  |
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

project_table
..............................................
|  Project_id  |  user_id  |  Date_assigned  |
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

I have two table, one is User_table, another is Project_table!
I need to generate report from these two tables!

Required Output is:

```
..................................................................
|  user_name |   0 - 10 Days  |   10 - 20 days |  20 - 30 days   |
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

Output table contains count of projects assigned to particular user in last 0 to 10 days! 
another columns contains count of project assigned within 10 to 20 days from current day.
and last column contains count of project assigned within 20 to 30 days from current day.

This is the SQL query which i tried:

```
select 
User_table.User_Name, COUNT(1)Project_0_to_10 
from user_table
INNER join Project_table as tb_project on tb_project.DateAssigned 
between  DATEADD(DD,-10,GETDATE()) and DATEADD(DD,0,GETDATE()) and
tb_project.user_id=User_table.User_id
group by user_table.user_name
```

This gives the output in this format

```
  ...................................
  |  user_name  |  Project_0_to_10  |
  '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
```

I am unable to find the count for other two columns!
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. Since you know how to create

```
-------------------------------
| user_name | Project_0_to_10 | 
-------------------------------
```

I'm sure that you can also create

```
--------------------------------
| user_name | Project_10_to_20 | 
--------------------------------
```

and

```
--------------------------------
| user_name | Project_20_to_30 | 
--------------------------------
```

right? Let's call those SQLs A, B and C. Now all you need to do is to *combine* them:

```
WITH 
  A AS (/* your A SQL here */),
  B AS (/* your B SQL here */),
  C AS (/* your C SQL here */)
SELECT COALESCE(a.user_name, b.user_name, c.user_name)
     , COALESCE(A.Project_0_to_10, 0)
     , COALESCE(B.Project_10_to_20, 0)
     , COALESCE(C.Project_20_to_30, 0)
  FROM A
       FULL OUTER JOIN B ON A.user_name = B.user_name
       FULL OUTER JOIN C ON B.user_name = C.user_name
```

The FULL OUTER JOIN ensures that all users are listed, even if they only appear in one of A, B or C. COALESCE ensures that `0` is shown in the respective column for users not listed in one of A, B and C.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a conditional count for example. This can be realized like this:

```
-- Create demo data
CREATE TABLE #user(user_id int identity(1,1), user_name nvarchar(50))

INSERT INTO #user(user_name) VALUES(N'A'),(N'B')

CREATE TABLE #projects(project_id int, user_id int, date_assigned datetime)

INSERT INTO #projects(project_id, user_id, date_assigned)
VALUES  (1,1,GETDATE()),(1,2,DATEADD(Day,-11,GETDATE())), (2,2,DATEADD(day,-11,GETDATE())), (3,2,DATEADD(day,-21,GETDATE())),
        (2,1,DATEADD(day,-21,GETDATE())),(3,1,DATEADD(day,-21,GETDATE()))

-- your part
SELECT u.user_name, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN p.date_assigned BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-10,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) last_10_days,
    SUM(CASE WHEN p.date_assigned BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-20,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(day,-11,GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) last_20_days,
    SUM(CASE WHEN p.date_assigned BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(day,-21,GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) last_30_days
FROM #user as u
INNER JOIN #projects as p
        ON u.user_id = p.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_name

-- cleanup
DROP TABLE #projects
DROP TABLE #user
```

Comment: +1. My solution is more general (for combining columns of different information), but yours is much more elegant for the current problem at hand.

Comment: Thanks in the first idea I tried to use pivot but then I realized that this is to complicated for this simple task. :-)